# Restoring version in Document Library causes unhandled exception when not checked out

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, error, versioning, check-out

We have a Sharepoint 2013 Foundation installation, with a document library that has check-out requirement activated.

When the user tries to restore an older version of a document, the following error is generated:

[image: Error]

This is pretty annoying, as the end-user will panic when confronted with this.

Any idea on how to catch this error and maybe display a nicer message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disable debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231550.aspx), change the following XML in the web.config file:

- Turn off the call stack (`CallStack="false"`)
- Enable custom errors in Visual Studio (`<customErrors mode="On" />`)
- Disable compilation debugging (`<compilation debug="false">`)

Comment: That's no solution as it gives the user no hint as to what happened.

Comment: The user will get nice SharePoint popup window with the same message text but without terrible ASP callstack information.

Comment: As far as i can see, he will get this error message: ![nice error](http://i.imgur.com/HbDC8yl.png)

Comment: You have made a mistake somewere in web.config. Check your modifications and fix it.

Comment: Ok, got it to work! Sorry, there were one web.config where i forgot to agjust the settings!